# ASP.NET Nested databinding - accessing parent dataitem

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, eval, repeater, formview

I have a formview and inside it's itemtemplate a repeater. I need to access the dataitem from formview inside the repeater.

Something like this

```
<asp:FormView runat="server" ID="EvaForm" ItemType="Item1" DataKeyNames="ProfileId" EnableViewState="true">
  <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="ProfileImages" ItemType="ProfileImage">
    <ItemTemplate>
     <a href="<%# LinkHelpers.GetProfilePath(Item.ProfileId, >>>>ITEM1 HERE<<<<.CreateDate) & Item.ImagePath%>" onclick="return false;">
```

An example with EVAL also together with an example with ItemType would be greatly appreciated.
All this is inside a User Control, don't think this will make difference.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <a href="<%# LinkHelpers.GetProfilePath(Item.ProfileId, DataBinder.Eval(Container.NamingContainer.NamingContainer, "DataItem.CreateDate").ToString()) + Item.ImagePath %>" onclick="return false;">
</ItemTemplate>
```

Alternatively, you can use server controls to display hyperlinks and set the `NavigateUrl` property in code-behind:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="ProfileImages" ItemType="ProfileImage" OnItemDataBound="ProfileImages_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="ProfileLink" OnClientClick="return false;" />
    </ItemTemplate>
<asp:Repeater>
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void ProfileImages_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    var profileImage = (ProfileImage) e.Item.DataItem;

    ((HyperLink) e.Item.FindControl("ProfileLink")).NavigateUrl = LinkHelpers.GetProfilePath(profileImage.ProfileId, ((Item1) EvaForm.DataItem).CreateDate.ToString()) + profileImage.ImagePath;
}
```

Comment: It works! I tryed the first solution in declarative .aspx code.
I made some testing with parent/container/namingcontainer but for some reasing I always ended up too far in the control tree... up to the main page controls just with parent.namingcontainer if I remember well (and all this stuff is inside a user control..).
I imagine that Container refers to ItemTemplate, NamingContainer to the Repeater and the other NamingContainer to the FormView right?

Comment: But I was trying to access data with ItemType and not with Eval wich in this scenario seems not possible right?

Comment: AFAIK, `Container` is a reference to the `RepeaterItem` instance representing the current data item, so it's `NamingContainer` property refers the repeater, and then to the form view.